# Timeout if a thread doesn't return within a specified period

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I would like to execute a lambda function asynchronously in MSVC C++. But if the function doesn't return the result within the specified duration, then the caller should just return with a timeout flag, leaving the thread detached so that it can later exit in a clean memory safe way.

I was able to somewhat achieve this using std::async and std::future, but my implementation is somehow leaking memory due to some bug. How to achieve the same behavior using std::thread + detach semantics?

```
 auto f = std::make_shared<std::future<T>>();
 *f = std::async(std::launch::async, [f, fun]() { return fun(); });

 auto status = f->wait_for(timeoutInSeconds);

 if (status == std::future_status::timeout)
 {
    return std::make_tuple(false, T{});
 }

 return std::make_tuple(true, f->get());
```

Comment: It might be more reliable to pass the timeout value into the function, and add code to the function that makes it voluntarily return early after the specified amount of time has passed.  That way there's no need to detach the thread, and no concerns about "leftover"/abandoned threads hanging around, using up CPU time, and potentially causing problems (e.g. during process shutdown)

Comment: I don't own that part of the code so cannot modify it.